# SELECT most viewed for the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve the most viewed pages for a 24 hour period, yet I have not created a 1 to 1 relationship between the pages(posts) and the view count.

`articles table`

```
  id |   title   | content |   created  | view_count
-----+-----------+---------+------------+------------
  1  |  title-1  |  info-1 | 1386478352 |   2
  2  |  title-2  |  info-2 | 1386532855 |   90
  3  |  title-3  |  info-3 | 1386637325 |   25
  4  |  title-4  |  info-4 | 1386812249 |   5
  5  |  title-5  |  info-5 | 1387094028 |   10
```

I'm using the following to retrieve the most viewed of all time, but I need to reset this every 24 hours.

`SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY view_count DESC`

Is there a way I can use information_schema for this instead of creating a 1 to 1 relationship between the articles and the view count and storing each time the article is viewed with the time the page was requests?

Comment: Very good point, thanks.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch: So what would you recommend? A record for every view with a foreign key to the article and a timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not using any implementation detail of the underlying DBS. You will have hard times with migration/updates.

That said I suggest a simple 1:n relation Pageview(articleId, viewdate). Each user view adds a timestamp into Pageview. Then you can easily join, aggregate and do whatever you want with that information.

```
SELECT articles.*, COUNT(*) views24h
    FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN pageview ON pageview.articleId = articles.Id
               AND pageview.viewdate > SUBDATE(NOW(),1)
    GROUP BY article.id
    ORDER BY views24h DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I figured as much, seemed to be the most efficient way of achieving this, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your database model.

For example create a table named  with the columns `date` and `article_id`.

Then insert for every view a new row. Like:

```
INSERT INTO views (date, article_id) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),1)
```

Now you can make queries like this which return the views within the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM views WHERE article_id = 1 AND date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400
```

This would return all visits of the article with 1 one in the last 24h.

Comment: @ssedano That still doesn't show 24h. In case you view at 0055 and clean at 0100, the count will show 0 views at 0105, even though you viewed 10 minutes ago.